# Conditionally use a variable group in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I know that it is possible to conditionally set a variable in azure pipelines yml.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion

Is it also somehow possible to conditionally use a variable group?

Let's say if a pipeline run variable is set or has a certain value then the pipeline shall use a variable group. If not then the group shall not be used.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible like here for instance:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none

variables:
  isProd: true

stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Build and restore
  variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isProd'], 'false') }}:
    - group: QA
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isProd'], 'true') }}:
    - group: PROD
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo $(name)
```

Comment: Ok. My variables are on top (= template) level. I will try it on stage level. Thank you

Comment: I tried it. I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I try to run it.
In my scenario the variable "isProd" is not defined as a template variable but as a pipeline variable.
My use case is the following I want to allow certain users of my pipeline on demand to add new variable (values) to override the default variables. I could use parameters but then people need to change their yml file for that. I want the people to customize the pipeline behaviour (via the variables) without forcing them to change their yml file that uses my pipeline template.
Any ideas?

Comment: It will not work if variables are not part of the YAML file. That's the limitation, they have to be known at compilation time, not at runtime like it is with pipeline variables.

Comment: OK. I now also assume that. Thank you