# Azure pipelines: parametrized variable group

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 variable groups defined and I want to use one or the other depending on the source branch that is triggering the pipeline:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - test
    - release/*

variables:
  - name: isStaging
    value: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test')]
    
  - name: isRelease
    value: $[startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/')]

  - name: variableGroup
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test') }}: 
      value: test_env_vars
    ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/') }}:
      value: prod_env_vars
```

Then I'd like to use the `$(variableGroup)` when running a stage like this:

```
stages:
- stage: Intro
  variables:
    - group: $(variableGroup)
  jobs:
       [...]
```

But this setup fails with the following error:

```
The pipeline is not valid. Stage Intro: Variable group $(variableGroup) could not be found. The variable group does not exist or has not been authorized for use.
```

My guess is that is simply not possible at the moment to set the variable group to a runtime variable. Is this the case?

Comment: Found something that solves my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68308123/conditionally-use-a-variable-group-in-azure-pipelines

Comment: Fell free to post you answer, that would probably help someone else in the future

Comment: It solves my problem but it doesn't answer my question. I'd still prefer to use the variable as in my example rather than the conditional as described in the link.

Comment: Are you defining your stages in the same file or inside a template ?

Comment: You should be able to use this syntax: `- group: ${{ variables.variableGroup }}`

Comment: Re ```- group: ${{ variables.variableGroup }}```. Is this available at run-time? As per my example, I am setting ```variableGroup``` in the file, so I am not sure that works.

Comment: Yeah that would be available at run-time. I gave it a try with everything in one file and that was working for me